# Move a LVM partition

Tags: partition, lvm, gparted, partition-table

I have a dual boot, and I never use Windows, but because I'm nice I wanted at the beginning to cut my hard drive in two equal parts, Windows on the left part, Linux on the right part. But then Linux ran out of space, so I shrinked Windows, and because I used a LVM partition, I created a new partition and share them on the logical partition. But now linux still runs out of space, and I'm thinking that it is strange to create tons of small LVM partitions, so I'm thiking to move the second LVM partition I created and extend it so that I just keep 2 partitions.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsblk -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible, the easiest option would be to use something like gparted, available from here: https://gparted.org/livecd.php

A simple guide on resizing can be found here
https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

once the partition is resized, reboot and use

```
pvresize /dev/<device_name>
lvresize -l +100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/<lvname>
```

-r flag is important as it will also resize the filesystem

There is a decent guide on this page:
http://ryandoyle.net/posts/expanding-a-lvm-partition-to-fill-remaining-drive-space/

**BE WARNED: If you have critical data on the filesystem I would backup before hand.**

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything is possible. The question is: Is it worth it?

I don't think there is a tool to do this. Resizing PVs will not be enough unless you are fearless enough to move a shrunk partition with `dd`.

For this to be "easy" the PVs have to be aligned to PE size (probably 4MiB); not to the beginning of the drive but towards each other. Then you could

1. save the PE positions of the later PVs from `/etc/lvm/backup`
2. delete the later PVs
3. extend the first (and only remaining) PV
4. do the math and adapt the PE offset in the definition in `/etc/lvm/backup` (or rather in a copy of that data before the PVs were deleted)
5. load the changed data with `vgcfgrestore`